# QML: 'Steal' events from dynamic MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml

I'm currently trying to implement a *drag-to-create* mechanism in QML, but I've hit upon a problem where I need the newly created `MouseArea` to become the target of mouse events even though the original `MouseArea` hasn't had a mouse button release event yet.

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: base
        width: 20
        height: 20

        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            property var lastPoint
            property var draggedObj: null

            function vecLength( vec ) {
                return Math.abs( Math.sqrt( Math.pow( vec.x, 2 ) +
                                            Math.pow( vec.y, 2 ) ) );
            }

            onPressed: lastPoint = Qt.point( mouse.x, mouse.y )
            onPositionChanged: {
                if ( !draggedObj ) {
                    var diff = Qt.point( mouse.x - lastPoint.x,
                                         mouse.y - lastPoint.y );
                    if ( vecLength( diff ) > 4 ) {
                        draggedObj = dragObj.createObject( window );
                    }
                }

                mouse.accepted = !draggedObj;
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: dragObj

        Rectangle {
            width: 20
            height: 20

            color: "blue"

            Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
            Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
            Drag.hotSpot.y: 10

            MouseArea {
                id: dragArea
                anchors.fill: parent

                drag.target: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this code and try it, you will see that dragging in the red `Rectangle` causes the creation of the draggable blue `Rectangle`, but it won't follow the mouse because the red `MouseArea` is still receiving the mouse events despite the blue `MouseArea` being above it.

Is there any way of forcing the blue `MouseArea` to receive the mouse events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced with this before and had a beginning of solution in my attic.

The trick here is calling [`QQuickItem::grabMouse()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#grabMouse) and sending a mouse press event to the newly created object.
Unfortunately I believe this can only be done from c++.

I then created a helper class to expose this functionality to qml:

#### `MouseGrabber.h`

```
#ifndef MOUSEGRABBER
#define MOUSEGRABBER

#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MouseGrabber : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQuickItem* target READ target WRITE setTarget NOTIFY targetChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool active READ active WRITE setActive NOTIFY activeChanged)

public:
    explicit MouseGrabber(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), m_target(nullptr), m_active(true) {  }
    QQuickItem* target() const { return m_target; }
    bool active() const { return m_active;}


signals:
    void targetChanged();
    void activeChanged();

public slots:
    void setTarget(QQuickItem* target)
    {
        if (m_target == target)
            return;
        ungrabMouse(m_target);
        if (m_active)
            grabMouse(target);
        m_target = target;
        emit targetChanged();
    }
    void setActive(bool arg)
    {
        if (m_active == arg)
            return;
        m_active = arg;

        if (m_active)
            grabMouse(m_target);
        else
            ungrabMouse(m_target);

        emit activeChanged();
    }

private:
    static void grabMouse(QQuickItem* target)
    {
        if (target)
        {
            target->grabMouse();
            QMouseEvent event(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPointF(), Qt::LeftButton,  QGuiApplication::mouseButtons(), QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers());
            QGuiApplication::sendEvent(target, &event);
        }
    }

    static void ungrabMouse(QQuickItem* target)
    {
        if (target)
            target->ungrabMouse();
    }

    QQuickItem* m_target;
    bool m_active;
};

#endif // MOUSEGRABBER
```

This could have been made more convenient by directly calling slots instead of manipulating proprieties, but that's what I had in stock. For example a slot called `grabMouseUntilRelease(QQuickItem* item)`, that grabs the mouse for this item, listen for a mouse release event with `installEventFilter` and ungrab it automatically.

---

Register the class so it can be instantiated in QML with `qmlRegisterType` somewhere in your code :

```
qmlRegisterType<MouseGrabber>("com.mycompany.qmlcomponents", 1, 0, "MouseGrabber");
```

---

After that you can instantiate a MouseGrabber in QML and use it by modifying its proprieties ( `target` and `active` ) :

#### QML

```
import com.mycompany.qmlcomponents 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: base
        width: 20
        height: 20

        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            property var lastPoint
            property var draggedObj: null

            function vecLength( vec ) {
                return Math.abs( Math.sqrt( Math.pow( vec.x, 2 ) +
                                           Math.pow( vec.y, 2 ) ) );
            }

            onPressed: lastPoint = Qt.point( mouse.x, mouse.y )
            onPositionChanged: {
                if ( !draggedObj ) {
                    var diff = Qt.point( mouse.x - lastPoint.x,
                                        mouse.y - lastPoint.y );
                    if ( vecLength( diff ) > 4 ) {
                        draggedObj = dragObj.createObject( window );
                        grabber.target = draggedObj.dragArea; // grab the mouse
                    }
                }

                mouse.accepted = !draggedObj;
            }
        }
    }
    MouseGrabber {
        id: grabber
    }

    Component {
        id: dragObj

        Rectangle {
            property alias dragArea: dragArea
            width: 20
            height: 20

            color: "blue"

            Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
            Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
            Drag.hotSpot.y: 10

            MouseArea {
                id: dragArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
                onReleased: {
                    if (grabber.target === this)
                        grabber.target = null; // ungrab the mouse
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of `grabMouse()`, but it looks like just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is way too much over engineered.
There is no need to steal the mouse events in your situation, you just want to update the position of the dragged blue rectangle in the onPositionChanged handler (or with a `Binding` or directly inside the `Rectangle` component).

Wrtiting this in your `MouseArea` is enough :

```
onPositionChanged: {
    if ( !draggedObj ) {
        var diff = Qt.point( mouse.x - lastPoint.x,
                             mouse.y - lastPoint.y );
        if ( vecLength( diff ) > 4 ) {
            draggedObj = dragObj.createObject( window );
        }
    } else { //update the position of the dragged rectangle
        draggedObj.x = mouse.x - draggedObj.width/2;
        draggedObj.y = mouse.y - draggedObj.height/2;
    }
}

onReleased: draggedObj = null
```